# How to add a checkbox to a GridView and select/deselect based on a SQL table row value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, datatable

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" ID="gvSubTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SN" HeaderText="SN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ST" HeaderText="ST" />
        <%-- ADD ANOTHER COLUMN HERE WITH THE CHECKBOX --%>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code-behind:

```
string strST = @"SELECT 
            ,A345 'SN'
            ,M3w 'ST'
            ,A667 'CT' -- 0 for not complete and 1 for complete
        FROM [mydb].[dbo].[table1]";

public DataTable RT()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = strST;

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

gvSubTasks.DataSource = RT();
gvSubTasks.DataBind();
```

How can I add a checkbox in my gridview per row, with a header "Complete" and based on the `CT`, pre-select the checkbox if it is `1` and not select the checkbox if it is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this for a column with checkbox

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CT").ToString() == "1" ? true : false %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
  <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="CT" HeaderText="CT" </asp:CheckBoxField>
```

if CT is a `CHAR` value you can modify your statement like `CASE WHEN CT = '1' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as CT`